# How to apply odd and even color to a 5 column list

Tags: html, css

This list display's the background color for 1st line and 2nd line different if the column count is even. When I change the column count to 5 the line color no longer applies, it shows color to each field instead of each line, because row count is also 5. How to keep the custom row count? or any other way to apply background color to odd and even lines for 5 columns ?

```
<ul id="list">
            <li>Peter</li>
            <li>Mary</li>
            <li>qaul</li>
            <li>Allen</li>
            <li>James</li>
            <li>Vicki</li>
            <li>Brock</li>
            <li>Dana</li>
            <li>Frank</li>
            <li>Gil</li>
            <li>Helen</li>
            <li>Peter</li>
            <li>sadf</li>
            <li>Paul</li>
            <li>cad</li>
            <li>Hyad</li>
            <li>k;pg</li>
            <li>werd</li>
            <li>radn</li>
            <li>vrank</li>
            <li>Gil</li>
            <li>zelen</li>
</ul>

#list {
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 0px;
 }


#list li {
  border-left:1px solid #dedede;
  border-top:1px solid #dedede;

}

#list li:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #fff;

}
#list li:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background: #efefef;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/3625/

Comment: Your fiddle looks correct in Chrome. Have you fixed your problem, or do you want to provide more information as to what's not working where?

Comment: when u change the column count  to 5 you see difference

Comment: Didn't notice the column count. I assumed it was an example of the problem. Does the list order matter?

Comment: yeah I need some kind of code to break the long list, so I have choosed this ccs3 method.

Comment: So the order does matter, or doesn't? If not, just float the `<li>`, add a percentage width and use `:nth()` CSS selector.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should not use CSS3 column-count property. Because in this situation, the row amount is relative to the li's amount. Now, you have 22 li markups, when you add it to 25, the background will be wrong even you don't change column-count from 6 to 5.

You may change your HTML from a ul to a table, it is easy to control the row's background.

Thanks!